# Triple quoted multi line string throwing EOF error

Tags: python, python-2.7, string-literals

I am trying to pass a multi line string. The string is a set of commands that are to be executed on a remote machine.

I know I can execute the command using ssh in subprocess module, but due to the requirement constraint I have to pass it as a string.

```py
    some_variable = "python -c \"exec('''import subprocess\nsubprocess.Popen(\"{}\")''')\"".format(file_path)
    execute_cmd_on_remote(some_variable)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
u'  File "<string>", line 1
    exec(\'\'\'import subprocess
                            ^
SyntaxError: EOF while scanning triple-quoted string literal
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets see what this turns into:

```
"python -c \"exec('''import subprocess\nsubprocess.Popen(\"{}\")''')\""
```

Python internally removes one escape layer:

```
python -c "exec('''import subprocess
subprocess.Popen("<file_path>")'''"
```

This now has a 'raw' newline, meaning that the remote shell/cmd-executer sees two lines and will execute two commands:

- `python -c "exec('''import subprocess`
- `subprocess.open("<file_path>")'''`

I am surprised that the shell does this without error, but nontheless, the `python`-command receives the following string:

```
exec('''import subprocess
```

This is now shows where the exception comes from. To fix, just add more layers of escape to the newline:

```
"python -c \"exec('''import subprocess\\nsubprocess.Popen(\"{}\")''')\""
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time, when there are slashes in the variable, i've faced this kind of errors. 
Let's see, what your variable is storing.

> some_variable = "python -c \"exec('''import
>   subprocess\nsubprocess.Popen(\"{}\")''')\"".format(file_path)

This will store:

> python -c "exec('''import subprocess

and

> subprocess.Popen("")'''"

in two different lines.

Due to the line changing in the variable, python is creating an exception.

One of the solution i've used is using double slashes:

```
 "python -c \"exec('''import subprocess\\nsubprocess.Popen(\"{}\")''')\""
```

That'll solve the problem of line changing, but it is sometimes confusing, when there are many slashes in the variable string that has to be stored.

Second solution is use of Python Raw String:
Python raw string is created by prefixing a string literal with ‘r’ or ‘R’. Python raw string treats backslash as a literal character.

So, rather than counting the slashes and converting them into double slashes, just you've to do is this:

```
some_variable = r"python -c \"exec('''import subprocess\nsubprocess.Popen(\"{}\")''')\"".format(filepath)
```

This will store the string as it is in the variable:

```
python -c \"exec('''import subprocess\nsubprocess.Popen(\"ATS 2.pdf\")''')\"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `\"{}\"` with `'{}'`.